# Where did my Candy Box 2 save go?

Tags: candy-box-2

I closed my candy box tab and when i opened the game again it was at the start again! how can I stop this from happening, i am using chrome on mac. is there any way to get my save back?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Saves are stored as follows:

```
https://candybox2.github.io/?slot=1 
https://candybox2.github.io/?slot=2 
etc...
```

Bookmark these links. Hopefully you had auto-saving on.

Comment: Yep. If you scroll down on the "save game" screen there are links to load your game

Comment: This did not help me, and I had auto-saving on. Is there any other way to get back your save?